# FFTW3 DFT 2D always return NaN

Tags: c++, fftw, dft

I'm trying to do DFT for a real 2D matrix using FFTW3.
this is my code snippet:

```
size_t nyh = ny/2 + 1;
out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc ( sizeof ( fftw_complex ) * nx * nyh );

plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d ( nx, ny, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

fftw_execute ( plan_forward );
```

where `in` is a `double*` each value is at order of e-270.

my problem is that out contains always `-nan` values.

Is there any trick to get correct values?

Thank you

---

Comment: Can you produce an example with full code and data? Without that we wont have much luck in reproducing your issue. However its worth noting that a single NaN in the input will result in NaNs everywhere, so be sure to clean them all out before transforming.

Comment: The code you posted seems correct. Could you post more code or a minimal piece of code which reproduces the error ? You can check that allocation works fine by adding `if(out==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}` and that the fftw_plan is actually created by `if(plan_forward==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"fftw_plan creation failed\n");exit(1);}`

Answer (score 1):

Thank everybody.

The problem which i was running in was not due to FFTW3 library and my code was correct despite of it's weakness.

My problem came from the input that i feed to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d` function which is issued from a `cv::Mat` image. So, I post the error i did to help anyone getting this trouble:)

I convert `cv::Mat` to a `vector<vector<double> >` using this function:

```
static MatrixOfDouble _convertMat( cv::Mat& inMat)
{
    MatrixOfDouble result;

    for (int i = 0; i < inMat.rows; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<double> row;
        for (int j = 0; j < inMat.cols; ++j)
        {
            row.push_back(inMat.at<double>(i, j));
        }
        result.push_back(row);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And Then i liniarize the returned matrix to feed the dft function.

But some of result matrix elements was NaN.

As a fix, i get cv::Mat element as long instead of double:

```
row.push_back(inMat.at<long>(i, j));
```

Good luck for everyone trying to solve this issue.

Comment: As a general advice for filling vectors, take a look at [this](https://www.acodersjourney.com/6-tips-supercharge-cpp-11-vector-performancehttps/) . `push_back` has to resize the vector each time. 
Assuming each row has the same length, declaring the vector `std::vector<long> row(inMat.cols)` initialises the vector such that it can be filled in the `j` loop: `row[j] = inMat.at<long>(i,j)`. This saves a lot of time :)